# DNS query from active directory is reaching reaching firewall in the same subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

DNS query for root dns from active directory is reaching firewall which is in the same subnet. Default route for this active directory is L3 router which has no route to firewall unless traffic is from proxy.Does any one faced this issue before? Any solution ?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you clarify?

Comment: When the Active Directory DNS cannot resolve a dns query it will send it to root hint servers.In our environment AD servers are not allowed to go to public.So when the sever tries to query root hint server the request will reach the L3 router which is the gateway of AD. But somehow the request is reaching the firewall in the same subnet of AD. In the L3 it is configured that only request for proxy will be routed to firewall.I am in confusion how this request reached the firewall.